# FET to be controlled with less than 1V Vgs

Tags: mosfet, switching

I have a simple switch circuit that is powered with a single 1.5V alkaline battery. I want to find a MOSFET(or other device) that will switch on when the  battery voltage is applied. I can find plenty of FETs with a Vgs of 1.5V but none that seem to switch on properly if the battery is a bit flat (ie 1V).

So I'm after Vgs of less than 1V, drain current is less than 100mA, Vds is the battery voltage, ie 1 to 1.5V.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use a BJT instead?

Comment: There are special boost controller which can start with ~200 mV if you are willing to increase the complexity a bit.

Comment: What advantage is the switch if all you need is a direct contact to the battery

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like a [MCH3383](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MCH3383-D.PDF) which is a P-channel MOSFET that is guaranteed to have less than 0.5 ohm Rds(on) at 0.9V.

Or perhaps the RYM002N05T2CL which is an N-channel part that has less than 9 ohms Rds(on) at 0.9V.

There are others. Try going to a distributor website and do a parametric search, then read the datasheet thoroughly (the distributor sites often contain errors and are best used as pointers to the manufacturer's data).

---

Another approach that is frequently used with a single-cell power supply is to use a boost regulator to increase the cell voltage to a more appropriate voltage such as 3.3V or 2.5V. Chips such the TI [TLV61225](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv61225.pdf) can do this (ON Semi has a number of them too). Keep in mind that the current drawn at the higher voltage will be reflected by a proportionally higher current from the battery (eg. 100uA at 3.3V will be more than 330uA from the battery at 1.0V).

Comment: MCH3383 http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MCH3383-D.PDF  looks like a good one. Nearly 500mA Ids at Vgs of 0.8V per chart at upper left of page 3, ID - Vs.  Available at Digikey.

Comment: The MCH3383 looks perfect. I didn't find anything like it when I did my searches. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NPN BJT could be the way to go. Current flow then is dependent on the base current vs the base voltage in a MOSFET.

Comment: If the OP wants to switch on power from the battery to a load it may be better to use a PNP BJT.

Comment: So a pullup resistor from the gate  to the battery to hold it in the offstate, and then a switch to pull the gate low to allow current flow to the load?

Comment: The PNP BJT does not have a gate.

Comment: Well, base then, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. A PNP transistor might well do the job I think I need to experiment. I need this circuit because I want to turn the unit ON when a mechanical switch is OPENED. My concern with this proposal is that when the transistor is off it might draw too much current.

Comment: Actually the problem with the BJT is that there will be a drop of 0.7V across Vce when its on. This means if the battery has dropped to 1V I only get 0.3V to my circuit!